# ORACLE SQL UPDATE STATEMENT IN TRIGGER NOT WORKING AFTER 2 ROWS

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BILL_TRG
BEFORE INSERT ON bill
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
d_id VARCHAR2(20);
doc_id VARCHAR2(20);
R_ID VARCHAR2(20);
p_name varchar2(20);

BEGIN
IF :NEW.BILL_NO IS NULL THEN
     SELECT BILL_NO_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.BILL_NO FROM DUAL;
END IF;
IF :NEW.BILL_DATE IS NULL THEN
       UPDATE BILL set BILL_DATE=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE); 
END IF;
IF :NEW.p_name IS NULL THEN
     SELECT p_name INTO :NEW.P_NAME FROM PATIENT WHERE P_ID=:NEW.P_ID;
END IF;
IF :NEW.P_GENDER IS NULL THEN
     SELECT P_GENDER INTO :NEW.P_GENDER FROM PATIENT WHERE P_ID=:NEW.P_ID;
END IF;
IF :NEW.P_ADDRESS IS NULL THEN
     SELECT P_ADDRESS INTO :NEW.P_ADDRESS FROM PATIENT WHERE P_ID=:NEW.P_ID;
END IF;
IF :NEW.D_NAME IS NULL THEN
     SELECT D_ID INTO DOC_ID FROM PATIENT WHERE P_ID=:NEW.P_ID;
     SELECT D_NAME INTO :NEW.D_NAME FROM DOCTOR WHERE D_ID = DOC_ID;
END IF;
IF :NEW.DATE_ADMISSION IS NULL THEN
     SELECT DATE_ADMISSION INTO :NEW.DATE_ADMISSION FROM PATIENT WHERE P_ID=:NEW.P_ID;
END IF;
IF :NEW.days_admitted IS NULL THEN
    UPDATE BILL SET DAYS_ADMITTED=abs(to_date(date_admission)-to_date(date_discharge));
END IF;
IF :NEW.room_charges IS NULL THEN
      SELECT room_id INTO R_ID FROM PATIENT WHERE P_ID=:NEW.P_ID;
      SELECT room_charges INTO :NEW.room_charges FROM room WHERE room_id=R_ID;
      UPDATE BILL SET ROOM_CHARGES=ROOM_CHARGES*DAYS_ADMITTED;
END IF;
IF :NEW.total_amount IS NULL THEN
    UPDATE BILL SET TOTAL_AMOUNT=ROOM_CHARGES+PATHOLOGY_FEES+D_FEES+MISCELLANEOUS;
END IF;
END;
/
```

First of all, I am using Oracle SQL Developer.
**In this trigger I used three update statements....they are working fine till two rows, after that.... value becomes null only.**

Can anybody help me with this?

[This update statement is working till 2 rows only.....after that it is not working.....I am attaching a screenshot of one of the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaSU9.png).

[Attaching 2nd picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODlfK.png)

Comment: can you show some sample data from table?

Comment: I already uploaded 2 pictures......please check that.

Comment: I just want to ask....why using an update statement in the trigger, 3rd record is not visible.

Comment: Please explain what the code is supposed to be doing.  I didn't downvote.  But you might be surprised to learn that non-working code generally does not do a good job of providing the context and explanation of the *intent* of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use `update` instead of direct assignment? you can't update a row that hasn't been inserted yet, so your last row entered will always be incorrect, and you will have updated all other rows in the table for no reason.

There appear to be a *number* of significant issues with your code and data model in general:

1. you are **storing dates as text**
2. you are **using `select into`** when a direct assignment (e.g. `NEW.BILL_NO := NVL(:NEW.BILL_NO,BILL_NO_SEQ.NEXTVAL);`) would work
3. you are **avoiding the use of SQL joins** when you should be using them to
   reduce the number of SQL executions (e.g. `SELECT D_NAME INTO :NEW.D_NAME FROM DOCTOR D, PATIENT P WHERE D.D_ID = P.D_ID AND P.P_ID = :NEW.P_ID;`)
4. you are **using `update`** to modify *all rows* of the same table that is
   calling the trigger *except* the row actually being inserted
5. there is **no format validation** on the to_date or to_char filters (which you wouldn't need if you were actually storing dates instead of text)
6. you use an **unnecessary function call** for abs when you could simply reverse
   the order of the two dates